# WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI?

Tags: spring, http-status-code-404

I have used @RestController in my sping contrller class.
   it is working fine as in case of api call when i use modelandview to         render view page it give the above 
  enter code hereWARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for      HTTP request with URI

```
 My web.xml 

<bean               class=
  "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cardreaderapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cardreaderapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>`enter code here`
 </web-app>

 My Controller class

  @RestController
   public class BasicController {
 @RequestMapping("/")
  public ModelAndView test()
    {
   System.out.println("Controller class invoked");
   return new ModelAndView("index");
}
 and my view exist at following location
webapp->web-INF->pages->index.jsp
```

Comment: perhaps you should config the path of your jsps

Comment: but i have give the exact path of my jsp so why it not found at that location, plz suggest.

Comment: did not see where you config your jsp's path.

Comment: i have updated the question where i show the path of view resource in spring configuration file. plz check!

Comment: try to replace `@RestController` with `@Controller`, maybe that would be helpful.

Comment: i had tried but still same error!